# Multiplying odd or even numbers in a list

Tags: python

I want to input a 8 digit number eg.`'12345678'`, remove and save the last digit (eg. `'8'`) reverse the 7 remaining digits (eg. `'7654321'`) and multiply by 2 the 1st,3rd,5th,7th (Odd) numbers.

I think I have solved the first two tasks but struggling with how to go about multiplying the odd numbers.

Code so far is:

```
cardnumber = input("Enter a number")
check_digit = int(cardnumber[7])
revnumber = cardnumber[-2:-9:-1]
```

Example:

- A user inputs '12345678'
- I then remove the last digit and store this as a check digit '8'
- I am then left with '1234567'
- I reverse this and have 7654321

I then want to multiply the odd numbers in the sequence - 1st, 3rd, 5th and 7th number:
so 7,6,5,4,3,2,1 becomes 14,6,10,4,6,2,2.

I'm very new to python so if you could explain I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Multiply by two the odd number or odd indexes?

Comment: What should happen if number that is to be  multiplied is greater than 5? (so that `number * 2` will be greater than 10) Could you post desired output?

Comment: @omri_saadon nope, `input` will return a string (assuming Python 3.x of course) so you can subscript it.

Comment: The question is rather unclear (cf the comments). Please edit your post to clarify the requirements and provide a couple input=>expected output examples.

Comment: so '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8' would be 14,6,10,4,6,2,2

Comment: Please put the examples in the post itself, answer the other questions (specially the one about what you want to double - odd numbers or number at odd indexing), and provide at least two or three different examples.

Answer (score 3):

1. First step - read the input:

```
number = input("Enter the number: ")
```

> 12345678

2. Second step - convert input to list:

```
numbers = map(int, str(number))
```

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

3. Third step - read last digit:

```
last = numbers[-1]
```

> 8

4. Fourth step - reverse the list:

```
rev = list(reversed(numbers[:-1]))
```

> [7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

5. Last step - generate a list with multiplied every two numbers:

```
multiplied = [i*2 if j % 2 == 0 else i for j, i in enumerate(rev)]
```

> [14, 6, 10, 4, 6, 2, 2]

Answer (score 3):

Try this:- it may be help you

```
number = 12345678
rev = 0
#this block gives reverse number
while number > 0:
    rem = number % 10
    rev = rev*10 + rem
number = int(number/10)
#number convert to list
number_list = [int(i) for i in str(rev)]

#take only 7654321
number_list1 = number_list[1:len(number_list)]
print(number_list1) #print 7654321

#for multiply by 2 the 1st,3rd,5th,7th (Odd) numbers
for i in range(len(number_list1)):
    if number_list1[i]%2 != 0:
        print(number_list1[i]*2)
```

output:-

```
[7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
14
10
6
2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cardnumber = input("Enter a number")
check_digit = int(cardnumber[7])
revnumber = cardnumber[-2:-9:-1]
```

now you may use `reduce` with `mul` operator:

```
from operator import mul
reduce(mul, for x in revnumber if int(x)%2=0)
```

this syntax is very compact (like your code), but if you want something more readable, consider using *for* loop instead.

Answer (score 1):

for beginners:

```
cardnumber = input("Enter a number")
check_digit = int(cardnumber[7])
revnumber = cardnumber[-2:-9:-1]

s = ''

for index,v in enumerate(revnumber):
    if index%2 == 0:
        s = s + v
    else:
        s = s + str(int(v)*2)
revnumber = int(s)

print(revnumber)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one-liner (not necessarily the best solution, but always nice to see):

```
>>> n = '12345678'
>>> s = ''.join(i if int(i) % 2 == 0 else str(2*int(i)) for i in n[-2::-1])
146104622
```

**Explanation**

`n[-2::-1]` is the slice of `n` that goes from the second-last element to the first (indexed `0`) by steps of `-1`, which corresponds to the input string minus the last character, reversed.

`(i if int(i) % 2 == 0 else str(2*int(i))` is a one-liner for the following:

```
if int(i) % 2 == 0:
    i
else:
    str(2*int(i))
```

The stuff in the outermost parenthesis is a generator, built from a `for` iteration over the processed string. It is more or less tantamount to:

```
l = []
for i in n[-2::-1]:
    if int(i) % 2 == 0:
        l.append(i)
    else:
        l.append(str(2*int(i)))
```

Finally, the `join` string method is called on the empty string `''` with the said generator as parameter.
It concatenates all the elements of the generator, separating them by the empty string, ie by nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this fully working example:

```
new_list = []
cardnumber = input("Enter a number: ")
check_digit = int(cardnumber[7])
revnumber = cardnumber[-2:-9:-1]

for number in revnumber:
    if int(number) % 2 != 0:
        new_list.append(int(number)*2)
    else:
        new_list.append(int(number))
print(revnumber)
print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
Enter a number: 12345678
7654321
[14, 6, 10, 4, 6, 2, 2]
```

And one more print output to get rid off brackets:

```
print(",".join(map(str, new_list)))
```

will give an output:

```
14,6,10,4,6,2,2
```

If you want to extract 9 from output items greater than 9:

```
new_list = []
cardnumber = input("Enter a number: ")
check_digit = int(cardnumber[7])
revnumber = cardnumber[-2:-9:-1]

for number in revnumber:
    if int(number) % 2 != 0:
        new_list.append(int(number)*2)
    else:
        new_list.append(int(number))
print(revnumber)

for i, number in enumerate(new_list):
    if new_list[i] > 9:
        new_list[i] -= 9
print(",".join(map(str, new_list)))
```

Comment: This seems easier, why do you add the new_list?

Comment: Just for readability and splitting original content from new one.

Comment: Great, can I then use a similar code to -9 from all of the numbers greater than 9?

Comment: `new_list = []
cardnumber = input("Enter a number: ")
check_digit = int(cardnumber[7])
revnumber = cardnumber[-2:-9:-1]

for number in revnumber:
    if int(number) % 2 != 0:
        new_list.append(int(number)*2)
    else:
        new_list.append(int(number))
print(revnumber)

for i, number in enumerate(new_list):
    if new_list[i] > 9:
        new_list[i] -= 9
print(",".join(map(str, new_list)))`

Comment: Im lost now!!!!!

Comment: I extended the answer above.

Answer (score 1):

```
k="12345678"
k_2=k[::-1][1:][1::2]    # get the digit with pair index
k_1=k[::-1][1:][0::2]    # get the digit with impair index, the odds
l_1=[str(int(x)*2) for x in k_1]  # multply per 2
result = [None]*(len(l_1)+len(k_2)) # merger two lists l_1 and k_2
result[::2] = l_1
result[1::2] = k_2
res = ''.join(result)
```

Output :

```
'146104622'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip_longest` from `itertools` module with `string slicing`:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def mul_odds(num):
    if len(num) != 8:
        return ''
    return ''.join(str(int(k)*2)+v for k, v in zip_longest(a[-2::-2], a[-3::-2], fillvalue=''))
```

Also, here is another example how you can solve your task using `map()`, `join()` and `string slicing`:

```
def mul_odds(num):
    if len(num) != 8:
        return ''
    return ''.join(map(lambda x: str(int(x[1])*2) if x[0]%2 != 0 else x[1], enumerate(num[-2::-1], 1)))
```

Both will output:

```
>>> mul_odds('12345678')
'146104622'
```